# Get an individual sum amount based on currency in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So i have a table as follows

```
Person      Currency      Price
Steve       GBP           10
Steve       GBP           20
Steve       EUR           30
Dave        USD           10
Dave        USD           10
Dave        EUR           20
John        EUR           30
John        GBP           20
John        USD           30
```

I want to have an output view which sums up each client based on how much they have spent by currency like so:

```
Person      Currency       Amount
Steve       GBP            30
Steve       EUR            30
Dave        USD            20
Dave        EUR            30
John        EUR            30
John        GBP            20
John        USD            30
```

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

So far i have tried a query like this:

```
SELECT  
Person,
Currency,
SUM(Price) As Amount

FROM Table
GROUP BY Currency
```

The logic of this being that it would order them based on their currencies but this has not worked, it is also telling me that i need to add more to the GROUP BY clause. What am i missing?

**UPDATE**

So far all the comments have been great but i left out a small detail.

The Currency is orignially a pair i.e USD/GBP and in order to select the one i need i am using the LEFT function

Example:

```
LEFT(CURRENCYPAIR,3) AS Currency,
```

Which is causing a list like this:

```
AUD
GBP
EUR
USD
USD
USD
```

Comment: `GROUP BY Person,
Currency`. (You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you select, which are not arguments to aggregate functions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

SELECT
Person,
Currency,
SUM(Price) As TotalSumOfCurrencyByPerson

FROM Table
GROUP BY Person,LEFT(CURRENCYPAIR,3)

The first problem is that you have only grouped by currency which, as there are only four types give you the sum of all GBP, AUD, USD and EURO. You need to add another layer of grouping to the query in order for it to sum each currency by person.

The second problem is that you ALSO need to group by what you select "LEFT(CURRENCYPAIR,3)".

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Use below GROUP BY query :

```
SELECT  Person,Currency,SUM(Price) As Amount
FROM Table
GROUP BY Person ,Currency
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use GROUP BY clausule correctly:

```
SELECT  
    Person,
    LEFT(CURRENCYPAIR,3) AS Currency,
    SUM(Price) As Amount        
FROM Table
    GROUP BY Person,LEFT(CURRENCYPAIR,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're very close.  Please try...

```
SELECT Person,
       Currency,
       SUM(Price) As Amount
FROM Table
GROUP BY Person,
         Currency;
```

Based on your question the data is grouped first by the Client, then for each Client by Currency.  After that you want the sum of Prices associated with that Client / Currency Grouping.

The above `GROUP BY` is performed first, then aggregate functions such as `SUM()` are performed on the data contained in each subgroup.

Also, consider giving your table a better name than `Table`. I suggest something like ClientCurrencyExpenditure, tblClientCurrencyExp, etc.